# How to inject Custom implementation of org.glassfish.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

Actually I need to override some functionality of `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider`,
For this I am planning through to provide custom implementation of `org.glassfish.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider` interface.

so here want to know, how I can inject this Custom implementation in to my environment. Currently my custom implementation is not getting executed after only putting `@Provider` annotation same as we need to do for customErrorHandler.